# wysihtml5-bootstrap cursor changing on submit

Tags: ruby, wysihtml5

I am working with the [wysihtml5-bootstrap](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) gem for Ruby and am using it as a live text editor along with Pusher. When I edit text inside one of the text boxes, it updates in the other open views of that save object. However, when my update function is called to save the content that is currently in the box and then update other open views of the text, the cursor moves to the beginning and almost renders the service unusable unless the user clicks after the last word to bring the cursor back to the ending position.

Using the wysihtml5 .html() function to update the view of the text, is it possible to save the cursor position and then have the cursor move to that location after the .html() function runs? I would love to have it so that the cursor does not move or is placed back at the last position after the .html() function runs.

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe("update");
        channel.bind("edit<%= @guide.id%>", function(data) {
          // alert('Attempting to set value: ' + data.message);
          var wysihtml5Editor = $('#some-textarea').data("wysihtml5").editor;

          // console.log(wysihtml5Editor);

          $(wysihtml5Editor.composer.element).html(data.message);
          console.log("New text is: " + $('#some-textarea').val());
        });
```

Above is the code which listens for a specific event that is triggered with Pusher.